# Programatically update field in another form

Tags: asp.net, sql-update, field, edit, code-behind

I have a "Date Updated" field in one form that is automatically populated with the date of the day when the update is made. I have an identical field in another form.

How can I programatically update the second field in the other table so that whenver the user clicks update on the first table, the second table updates as well.

The first "Date Updated" field is in a DetailsView while the second is in a GridView. So far I have:

> ```
>   GridView1.SetEditRow(GridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
>   Dim datebox As TextBox = GridView1.FindControl("DateUpdatedBox1")
>   datebox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
>   GridView1.UpdateRow(GridView1.Rows.Count - 1, False)
> ```

as part of an onItemUpdated event for the DetailsView. However, this isn't working. I'm getting an "object instance not set to an instance of an object" error on the 3rd line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find a control **inside** a GridView.

Are you sure it is there? Because I would expect it either outside the GridView or multiple occurrences inside.

Update after your comment:
You missed my point. I think you need to get the Row and find the textbox there:

```
  foreach (GridViewRow row in yourgridview.Rows)
        {
            TextBox datebox = (TextBox)row.FindControl("DateUpdatedBox");
}
```

Comment: It's definitely in there as a textbox in EditItemTemplate. There is another occurrence for the ItemTemplate, but that one's a label so that shouldn't be causing the problem. I think my problem before was that I wasn't putting the Gridview in Edit mode so it was grabbing the wrong control. However, I'm not sure if this code is grabbing it either.

Comment: I've changed the code snippet you offered a little and it is finding the correct control now and filling it with the date. However, the row is still in "edit" mode and I have to manually click the update linkbutton in the Gridview. Is there anyway to automatically commit the update or click the linkbutton from codebehind without additional user action?